# Lucene startOffSet should greater than endOffSet error

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using lucene 4.4. When I try to add Documents with shingle,WordDelimiter and stopwords filter factories, I am getting the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, startOffset=36945,endOffset=36943
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttributeImpl.setOffset(OffsetAttributeImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.shingle.ShingleFilter.incrementToken(ShingleFilter.java:323)

This exception is not for all doucments. These are for specific documents. Anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

Your synonym filter may be creating position increments of 0, and ShingleFilter does not handle 0 position increments.  (See [Lucene 3475](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3475))

I believe you should be able to deal with this by setting your `SynonymMap` rules with `KeepOrig` set to false.  Basically, you want to make sure that `SynonymFilter` doesn't create multiple terms as the same position.  If you are applying the same `SynonymFilter` at index time and query time, then you generally don't need to keep the originals.

Comment: I am using WordDelimiterFilterFactory too. will this cause the problem?

Comment: The issue has been fixed. I have just changed the order of filter factories. Anyway thanks for your help. Learned something from your answer. So upvote.

Comment: Unless my understanding is incorrect, just swapping the order of the two, while it may not cause any errors, won't that have the same effect as removing your SynonymFilter altogether, since your Synonymfilter is intended to look at tokens before they are combined into shingles?

Comment: Yes. So changing the order has an impact. I can send the file which is causing issue. How can I send it to u?

Comment: Yes, order is important.  You have a stream of tokens, and each filter you apply is applied in sequence, and works on the stream which the previous filter in the chain has split out.  If you apply SynonymFilter then LowercaseFilter, your synonym matching will be case sensitive.  The other way around, they will not be  (and your synonym defintions should all also be lowercase).  If you want to add more information, please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Dude I have a java file and the file which causes this issue. can I send these through mail? or I don't know how to ask in stackoverflow..

Comment: No, sorry, I don't wish to receive it via e-mail.  You may edit this question, or post a new one, whichever makes sense.  Add the code to your question (see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)), and a subset of the data which you are having an issue with.  If there is too much that you need to post, [try to narrow your problem down](http://sscce.org/#short).